# Screenshots of iframes taking by python selenium are cropped (both chrome and firefox webdrivers)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, python-imaging-library

I am trying to screenshot an image located inside an iframe in an ads creative in headless mode.
Indeed, I will have to screenshot many of such iframes and the final script will run on a remote server.

No matter what I have tried, screenshots always seem to be cropped when I use the headless mode of selenium.
I have seen that a few posts exist on this subject, but none of them have solved my issue.

Here is a list of things I already tried:

- Using either Firefox or Chrome webdrivers didn't help.
- Using different combinations of waits conditions didn't help either.

Below, there is a MWE of the code I am trying to run:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as OptionsFirefox
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as OptionsChrome


from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

test_url = "https://cdn-creatives.adikteev.com/Creatives/demoLink/MLEngine/index.html?MRAID_320X480_AWEM_CradleEmpires_Aug20/creative-e03f09e5.min.js"
id_iframe = "mainIframe"

# Setting up the driver.

# options = OptionsFirefox()
# options.headless = True
# driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

options = OptionsChrome()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Getting the url.
driver.get(test_url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, id_iframe)))
# Getiing the iframe with its informations:
elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, id_iframe)

#
location = elem.location
size = elem.size
left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']
ic(elem.location)
ic(elem.size)

# Waits (might help ?).
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(id_iframe))

# Saving screenshots:
# Complete screenshot.
img_png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()

driver.save_screenshot("full_screen_headless_on.png")

img_crop = Image.open(BytesIO(img_png))
img_crop = img_crop.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) # defines crop points
# Screenshot cropped to the Iframe.
img_crop.save( "iframe_screen_headless_on.png" ) # saves new cropped image

driver.quit()
```

[image: full_screen_headless_on.png]

[image: iframe_screen_headless_on.png]

If someone has a solution, that will be greatly appreciated :-) !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Selenuium.

In my case additional waiting after resolving the URL helped, for instance:

```
...

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, id_iframe))
)

...
```

I can't actually explain why it works like that, I didn't deep into the docs, but it helped.